# How can I make my livebox route to my external IP address for a computer in the DMZ?

Tags: router, firewall, ip, nat, dmz

I have a sagem livebox 2 (Fiber optic model), and have placed my computer in a DMZ. People from outside of my network can access my comp fine via its external dyndns.org address, yet when I try to call the public dyndns.org address from inside my network, I get redirected to the internal admin site on the router. How can I make it so that I can see my comp from the public address like everyone else? What kinds of questions should I be asking or looking into?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

See if there's an option in your router configuration to change the HTTP port of your administration interface to something other than 80.  If that's not possible, and you're only running a regular HTTP server and not a secure HTTPS server, change the router configuration to use HTTPS and not HTTP.

Also, if you're only running a web server, consider using the port forwarding feature of your router to only forward port 80 to the target computer.  You can do this for as many ports as you need.  This reduces the attack profile of your system by allowing the router to act as a firewall, instead of relying on the target computer's firewall.